# my resultSet return me 0 number of records but database has that values , when run same mysql query in mysql so return 1

Tags: java, mysql

here i get the values from text field

```
private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    String userName = txtUserName.getText();
    char[] passwordArray = txtPassword.getPassword();

    String password = " ";
    for(int i = 0; i < passwordArray.length; i++){
        password = password + passwordArray[i];
    }

    int numberOfRecords = 0;

    if(userName.equals("") || password.equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please fill the form properly:");
    }else{
        System.out.println("i am here");
        numberOfRecords = userServices.tryLogin(userName, password);
        System.out.println("after number of records");
        if(numberOfRecords == 1){
            this.dispose();
            mainForm.setVisible(true);
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Sorry user name or password is incorrect:");
        }
    }
    txtUserName.setText(" ");
    txtPassword.setText("");
}
```

here is my trylogin method

```
public int tryLogin(String userName, String password) {

    int numberOfRecords = 0;

    SQLQueryUtil sql = new SQLQueryUtil();
   sql.connect(false);
   String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `number_of_records` FROM `user` "
            + "WHERE `userName`='" + userName + "' AND `password`='" + password + "';";
    System.out.println(query);

    ResultSet resultSet;

    try{

       resultSet = sql.executeQuery(query);
        resultSet.isBeforeFirst();

       numberOfRecords = resultSet.getRow();

         System.out.println("number of Records =" + numberOfRecords);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        sql.disconnect();
    }
    System.out.println("i am here also..............................");
    return numberOfRecords;

}
```

When i click on login button then it show me the following result
driver loaded
Connection establish
Statements Created
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `number_of_records` FROM `user` WHERE `userName`=' ' AND `password`='  ';
number of Records =0

Comment: It looks like you are passing username and password empty

Comment: if i put  resultSet.isBeforeFirst() and numberOfRecords= resultSet.getRow() instead of resultSet.next()  and numberOfRecords= resultSet.getInt("number_of_records") ;it also return me 0.

Comment: vinay chhabra brother username and password will get from text field .because when i print query it show me the correct username and password.   here is the query   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `number_of_records` FROM `user` WHERE `userName`='wasif ' AND `password`=' zaman ';

Comment: use resultSet.last(); then try getRow();

Comment: And just for the record: you do not store plain passwords! Never ever! You have to securely hash them.

Comment: @ vinay chhabra . thank you brother it solve my current problem now it return 1

Comment: @GhostCat i store it only to test my problem its my first project in java

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the password with space. Just remove the space in password declaration and try .

```
String password = "";
for(int i = 0; i < passwordArray.length; i++){
    password = password + passwordArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The getRow() method retrieves the current row number, not the number of rows. So before starting to iterate over the ResultSet, getRow() returns 0.

So try in this way.

```
resultSet.last(); 
total = resultSet.getRow();
resultSet.beforeFirst();
```